# Is my table normalized?

Tags: database, normalization

I have MySQL database containing one table GreatPlaces. This table has 100 rows, where each row represents a different historically important place on the Earth, such as Forbidden City in Beijing or Pyramids in Egypt. It has following attributes:

```
ID - integer, primary key
NAME - varchar, candidate key
COUNTRY - varchar, containing duplicities
CONTINENT - varchar, containing duplicies
TYPE - varchar, containing duplicities
LONGITUDE - decimal, containing duplicities (some historical sites are in the same city)
LATITUDE - decimal, containing duplicities (same as for an attribute LONGITUDE)
STORY_PATH - varchar, candidate key, an URL link to the file system
DESCRIPTION_PATH - varchar, candidate key, an URL link to the file system
PICTURES_PATH - varchar, candidate key, an URL link to the file system
VIDEO_PATH - varchar, candidate key, an URL link to the file system
```

Is my table normalized? To fulfil 1NF, all the fields have to be atomic. The only problem could be values of attribute NAME, for example 'Pyramid of Khufu and the Sphinx' could be decomposed into a strings, but I guess this should be OK(?). Then I read that the table is in 2NF if is in 1NF and every non-prime attribute is dependent on every whole primary key. The problem is I dont know how to find out which attribute is non-prime one. I read a non-prime atribute is the one that cannot participate in creating a candidate key. But here, in my table I see that every attribute can make a candidate key together with ID, for example {ID, LATITUDE} can make candidate key.

So my question is if my assumption is right, that I do not have any non-prime attributes in the table. Then I assume the database should be automatically in 2NF and 3NF. Is this right?

Comment: In general, if you use auto-incrementing numbers for your primary keys, and don't duplicate your data across tables, your database is automatically normalized.  I do understand 1NF, 2NF and all that, but your life gets much simpler if you just use unique, numerical primary keys everywhere.

Comment: If I understand correctly, by creating auto-incrementing ID attribute, the table is normalized right away?

Comment: If you don't have duplication of information, yes.  You wouldn't duplicate someone's name and address in an invoice table; you would put their name and address in a Customer table, and link the invoice to the customer record.  I mention using unique numerical ID's for the primary keys because you have candidate key sprinkled all over your table descriptions.

Comment: I have just one table. And I do not understand completely what do you mean by duplicities. Duplicities between all the attributes, meaning that 2 rows have same values for ALL the attributes? For example, I have some rows having the same values for country, continent, longitude and latitude attribute, but it differs in name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of {ID, LATITUDE} is a [superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey).  That is, it satisfies the requirement that the key contain no duplicates, but the superkey contains more columns than are minimally necessary to be a candidate key.  Stated another way: *any candidate key is a subset of a superkey.*  So yes, your table has non-prime columns.

Using an auto-incrementing column isn't a magic way to make a table normalized.  You can still have tables that fail 3NF if the table has columns that depend on non-key columns.

For instance, your columns COUNTRY and CONTINENT are dependent on LONGITUDE/LATITUDE.  You can't say that a given Lat/Long is sometimes in Ireland and sometimes in Thailand, depending on the NAME value on a given row.  Thus you have non-key attributes that are dependent on something other than the candidate key(s).

---

Re comments

In normalization, "A depends on B" or "B functionally determines A" means "if I know a given value for B, then there can be only one possible value for A."  The notation is B → A.

The example is (Lat, Long) → (Country, Continent).  If you know the coordinates, then you  know unambiguously which country that's in.  I.e. the coordinates *functionally determine* the country.

The definition of 3NF is that B must be the whole candidate key, and A must be a non-key attribute.  In the example, B is (Lat, Long) and A is (Country, Continent).  So A is non-key and that's okay, but B is not a candidate key, and that's what breaks 3NF.

In this example it probably wouldn't be practical set up a lookup table for all possible Lat,Long combinations and map them to their respective country.  Strictly speaking, it doesn't comply with 3NF, but in this case, breaking 3NF is a more efficient choice.

You just have to be careful because someone might make a mistake: entering two rows with an identical Lat,Long pair, but accidentally associating it with two different countries.

Comment: `Using an auto-incrementing column isn't a magic way to make a table normalized` -- Of course not.  You still need to de-dupe, which I plainly stated.

Comment: @ BillKarwin - Thus you have non-key attributes that are dependent on something other than the candidate key(s) - that implies a table is not in 3NF?

Comment: Yes, that's because the definition of 3NF is that all non-key attributes must depend only on the key.

Comment: So what is the solution in this case? I do not understand how one can say that attribtue A is dependent on attribtue B. Is it just a matter of logical thinking?

Comment: @ Bill Karwin - thank you for a comprehensive explanation. Just want to mention that LAT, LON is are the coordinates of the place (represented by NAME attribute) within given COUNTRY, meaning that two rows with the same value of COUNTRY attribute may have different (but in some case also the same) values of LAT, LON attributes. Did you take this into account?

Comment: Right, that's why → has a direction.  If you know your coordinates, you know what country you are in.  However even if you know what country you are in, you may not know your exact coordinates.